# How would you make a function that adds random numbers from a list to reach a certain value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, random

the question title might be a little bit confusing so let me see if I can explain it a little better here. I want to create a function that will generate a sequence of numbers (in any order or combination) that are in a pre-defined list to add to a certain value.

IE.

```
var x = [6, 4, 3]; //pre-defined values
var n = 24; //the number I want to add too

function myFunc(values, goal) {
    //code for algorithm
    //return a sequence of numbers from the list that add to 24
}

myFunc(x, n)
```

Example Outputs from myFunc:

- 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 3 --> 24
- 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4 --> 24
- 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4 --> 24
- etc.

The algorithm would be able to return one of the many permutations that exist but I just came up with a couple for the sake of the question.

Responses don't have to be language-specific I just need a general idea/insight on how to create and structure this algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your purpose for the function to return *one* possible solution? If so, should it be a different one every time it is called? Or are you thinking of an iterator over all possible solutions in a random order?

Comment: Do you know anything about the values or the target, either limits on size, or that the values divide the target as in the example, or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force approach that keeps adding random values until the sum is `24` (return) or it's greater than `24` (restart). This may not be practical for large values.

```js
var x = [6, 4, 3]; //pre-defined values
var n = 24; //the number I want to add too

function myFunc(values, goal) {
  let result = [];
  while (true) {
    // Add random value
    result.push(values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]);
    // Calc sum
    var sum = result.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
    // If success, return
    if (sum == goal) return result;
    // If too large, start over
    else if (sum > goal) result = [];
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(myFunc(x, n));
}
```